# What does this line from a game mean?

Tags: grammatical-number

https://youtu.be/pGwqN71

> "We'll be even on that house you owe me."

What the heck does the ugly pig mean? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason Bigby owes Colin a house, and Colin is saying a couple thousand more cigarettes will cover the **cost** of the house, that Bigby will no longer owe Colin that house and they will be **even**.